# create a keyboard shortcut to type a character

Tags: shortcut-keys

I'm looking for and I can't find what I'm looking for

Is there a way or program to create a key combination to enter a  special character?

Actually I just want to press alt + 61 and it returns an "=" and so with several codes, I don't need all the ascii but I do need several.

Linux has so many years of life and there was never a way to achieve it?

Comment: You've provided no OS & release details, what you're asking is also dependent on the desktop being used (*and you've provided no details*)

Comment: Please edit your question and add the OS and version information in your question.

Answer (score 6):

• Also on Linux, there is a way to enter foreign characters by typing a code.

- Start entering a number by hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>u</kbd>
- Enter the four-symbol hexadecimal number of the code, e.g. 03B4 for the character δ, and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Find the codes of the character you want to enter in the tool "Characters".

• Instead of entering the codes, you can use the tool itself to copy a character to the clipboard, then paste it. You can search characters by name or find them in the different tabs. When you click a character, hitting <kbd>Enter</kbd> in the dialog that appears will copy it to the clipboard. You can paste it using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>

• Linux has for the long time that it exists [a system of the "Compose" key](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ComposeKey). It allows to enter special characters by 1) hitting a signal key, i.e. the "Compose" key (you set it yourself, could be e.g. <kbd>Control right</kbd>) and 2) some characters that will combine into a special character. e.g. <kbd>Compose</kbd><kbd>"</kbd><kbd>e</kbd> will result in the character **ë**.

• Inspect the possibilities of your keyboard layout. On a US international keyboard, there are many characters hidden under the right <kbd>AltGr</kbd> key and a character, e.g. <kbd>AltGr</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>:</kbd> yields **°**, <kbd>AltGr</kbd><kbd>m</kbd> yields **µ**.

• Finally, what you specifically asked, you can create a shortcut key that types a character using a utility `xdotool`. Suppose you want to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd> to type the character ‣. Create a shortcut, and enter the command

```
xdotool keyup ctrl+shift+p type ‣
```

The keyup statement simulate releasing the shortcut key because holding it down may interfere with the typing.