# Shortcut for type umlauts with compose key

Tags: 18.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

**How to define a shortcut for a small set of special characters produced by `compose` key?** I have a number of restrictions:

- My keyboard has a US layout but without `AltGr` key,
- I already have a working customized keybinding with `xmodmap` that shouldn't be changed (because I struggled A LOT to configure it for my old laptop with some broken keys),
- I need to type in two different layouts, English, Persian, and German,
- I want this shortcut to work in all environments (including terminal).

As the main difference between German and English alphabets is the existence of umlauts in the former, I decided to activate my `compose` key to type those. And it actually works. But the series of keys to produce any umlaut using `compose` is too cumbersome for me, and I rather define the following shortcuts:

- ä: `compose + a + :` --> `alt + a`
- Ä: `compose + A + :` --> `alt + ctr + a`
- similar approach for the other umlauts

The question is essentially similar to [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1360875/create-a-keyboard-shortcut-to-type-a-character). Yet, the answer to this question is painfully slow and seems not robust--For the given example in the solution, I had to use my shortcut at least twice to trigger type `‣` once). I'm aware of tools like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1147812/is-there-any-application-or-command-that-lets-you-insert-special-characters-uml/1147924#1147924). But, really, one should be able to define a shortcut for compositions with the built-in tools of ubuntu, right?

**Note**: I'm using 18.04 with the default Gnome as my desktop environment.

Comment: Please indicate what desktop environment you use. The dialogs to control these aspects depend between desktop environments

Comment: @vanadium I use the default gnome.